# Quartz Trigger looses prev fire time value on server startup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am facing a strange issue with Quartz scheduler. The cron job works fine and it updates `next_fire_time` and `prev_fire_time`. However when we restart our server the all the triggers previous fire time values are set to `-1`.

Configuration of quartz

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.dontSetAutoCommitFalse=false
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate 

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
          <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/quartz.properties"/>
          <property name="dataSource" ref="movesouqDataSource"/>
          <property name="jobFactory" ref="quartzJobFactory"/>
          <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
          <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
          <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
          <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
          <property name="triggers">
                 <list>
                      <!-- refrence jobs -->
                 </list>
          </property>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try setting the below value and test again

> overwriteExistingJobs to FALSE

Wondering whether that is causing the overwrite.